# grails 1.3.5 build seems to have issues with dependencies

Tags: grails, jenkins

I'm building several grails applications in jenkins.  After wiping out the workspace, the builds are failing and they fail in different places with what appears to be dependency issues. The same build from one run to the next will fail on indtalling different plugins.

For example when building a war file I get the following output:

> Installed plugin rest-client-builder-1.0.3 to location target\workvrgrails\plugins/rest-client-builder-1.0.3. ...
>        [java]    [delete] Deleting directory E:\programs\jenkins\jobs\ICM\jobs\CORE-ISITS\jobs\2.1\jobs\CI.bak\workspace\vrgrails\target\workvrgrails\plugins\jasypt-encryption-0.1.1
>        [java] Plugin rest-client-builder-1.0.3 requires version [2.0 > *] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.

As far as I know, the only thing that changed in the environment was that the jenkisn workspace that holds the code and the build output was deleted.  Any idea what might be going on?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear: `Plugin rest-client-builder-1.0.3 requires version [2.0 > ] of Grails which your current Grails installation does not meet. Please try install a different version of the plugin or Grails.`

Comment: that is not a dependency that we are pulling in directly.  It must be specified as a transient dependency.  We can get the build to work if we shift the dependencies in our application property file. The odd thing is that we are getting a similar message when calling set-version and we are not specifying any dependencies for this code to run.

Comment: Try grails dependency tree report

Comment: How to generate a dependency report: [link](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Command%20Line/dependency-report.html). From command line run `grails dependency-report`

Comment: what we noticed is that dependencies in the associated application.properties file was getting reordered in the build process.  It appears that the some dependencies that were pushed to the bottom, got pulled up in order and then pulled in other dependencies themselves that did not fit with our version of grails 1.3.5.  As far as I can tell we did not change anything on our end to cause this behavior.